# Having problems with a C++ program (for school) that requires 7 parallel Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

Lab Problem:

Write a program to keep track of a hardware store inventory. The store sells
various items. For each item in the store, the following information is kept:
item ID, item name, number of pieces ordered, number of pieces currently
in the store, number of pieces sold, manufacturer’s price for the item, and
the store’s selling price. At the end of each week, the store manager would
like to see a report in the following form:

Friendly Hardware Store
itemID itemName pOrdered pInStore pSold manufPrice sellingPrice
4444 Circular Saw 150 150 40 45.00 125.00
3333 Cooking Range 50 50 20 450.00 850.00
.
.
.
Total Inventory: $#########.##
Total number of items in the store: _____________

...

Input Format:

itemID
itemName
pOrdered manufPrice sellingPrice

Use seven parallel vectors to store the information. The program must contain at
least the following functions: one to input data into the vectors, one to display the
menu, one to sell an item, and one to print the report for the manager.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes

void getInventory (ifstream& infile, vector<string>& itemID, vector<string>& itemName,
                   vector<int>& pOrdered, vector<int>& pInStore, vector<int>& pSold,
                   vector<double>& manufPrice, vector<double>& sellingPrice);

void displayMenu (vector<string>& itemID, vector<string>& itemName, vector<int>& pOrdered,
                  vector<int>& pInStore, vector<int>& pSold, vector<double>& manufPrice,
                  vector<double>& sellingPrice);

void sellItem    (vector<string>& itemID, vector<string>& itemName, vector<int>& pOrdered,
                  vector<int>& pInStore, vector<int>& pSold, vector<double>& manufPrice,
                  vector<double>& sellingPrice);

void searchItem  (vector<string>& itemID, vector<string>& itemName, vector<int>& pOrdered,
                  vector<int>& pInStore, vector<int>& pSold, vector<double>& manufPrice,
                  vector<double>& sellingPrice);

void printReport (vector<string>& itemID, vector<string>& itemName, vector<int>& pOrdered,
                  vector<int>& pInStore, vector<int>& pSold, vector<double>& manufPrice,
                  vector<double>& sellingPrice);



//Driver Function: Open File, Get Inventory, Display Menu, Close File.

int main() {

    //Vectors

    vector<int> itemQuantity;
    vector<string> itemID;
    vector<string> itemName;
    vector<int> pOrdered;
    vector<int> pInStore;
    vector<int> pSold;
    vector<double> manufPrice;
    vector<double> sellingPrice;

    // External Inventory File

    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("inventory.txt");

    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening inventory file! " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    getInventory (infile, itemID, itemName, pOrdered, pInStore, pSold, manufPrice, sellingPrice);

    displayMenu  (itemID, itemName, pOrdered, pInStore, pSold, manufPrice, sellingPrice);

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}

// Get Inventory Definition

void getInventory (ifstream& infile, vector<string>& itemID, vector<string>& itemName, vector<int>& pOrdered,
                   vector<int>& pInStore, vector<int>& pSold, vector<double>& manufPrice, vector<double>& sellingPrice)

{
    // Declaring some Temp variables.
    
    string item;
    string name;
    int ordered;
    double mPrice;
    double sPrice;
    
    while (infile)
    {
        infile >> item;
        infile.ignore(100,'\n');  // process the new-line character
        getline(infile,name);
        infile >> name >> ordered >> mPrice >> sPrice;
        
        itemID.push_back(item);
        itemName.push_back(name);
        pOrdered.push_back(ordered);
        manufPrice.push_back(mPrice);
        sellingPrice.push_back(sPrice);
    }
    
    pInStore = pOrdered;
    

}

// Display Menu Definition

void displayMenu (vector<string>& itemID, vector<string>& itemName, vector<int>& pOrdered,
                  vector<int>& pInStore, vector<int>& pSold, vector<double>& manufPrice,
                  vector<double>& sellingPrice)
{
    char menuAnswer;
    cout << "Type 'C' to check if an item is in stock." << endl;
    cout << "Type 'S' to sell an item to a customer." << endl;
    cout << "Type 'R' to print an inventory report." << endl;
    cin >> menuAnswer;

    if (menuAnswer == 'C' || menuAnswer == 'c')
        searchItem(itemID, itemName, pOrdered, pInStore, pSold, manufPrice, sellingPrice);
    if (menuAnswer == 'S' || menuAnswer == 's')
        sellItem(itemID, itemName, pOrdered, pInStore, pSold, manufPrice, sellingPrice);
    if (menuAnswer == 'R' || menuAnswer == 'r')
        printReport(itemID, itemName, pOrdered, pInStore, pSold, manufPrice, sellingPrice);
}

// Sell Item

void sellItem (vector<string>& itemID, vector<string>& itemName, vector<int>& pOrdered,
               vector<int>& pInStore, vector<int>& pSold, vector<double>& manufPrice,
               vector<double>& sellingPrice)
{
    int itemNumber;
    int amtBought;
    double cash;
    char verifyItem;
    int i;

    
    cout << "Enter, or scan the Item ID. ";
    cin >> itemNumber;

    i = itemNumber;

    if (i != -1)
    {
        cout << "You are selling " << itemName[i] << ", which costs $"
             <<  sellingPrice[i] << "Is this correct? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        
        cin >> verifyItem;

        if (verifyItem == 'N' || verifyItem == 'n')
        {
            cout << "What item number is being purchased? " << endl;
            cin >> itemNumber;
        }

        cout << "How many items are being purchased? " << endl;
        cin >> amtBought;

        if (amtBought < 1)

        cout << "None of this item is being purchased!" << endl;

        else
        {
            if (pInStore[i] < amtBought)
                    cout << "Only " << pInStore[i] << " of these items can be sold." << endl;

            else
            {
                cout << "The total price of this transaction is " << amtBought * sellingPrice[i] << endl;
                cout << "Enter amount given." << endl;
                cin >> cash;

                
                pInStore[i] = pInStore[i] - amtBought;
                cout << "The change is $" << cash - (amtBought * sellingPrice[i]) << endl;
                cout << "Have a nice day!" << endl;
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}

// Search Item Definition

void searchItem (vector<string>& itemID, vector<string>& itemName, vector<int>& pOrdered,
                 vector<int>& pInStore, vector<int>& pSold, vector<double>& manufPrice,
                 vector<double>& sellingPrice)
{
    int number;

    cout << "Which item would you like to check?" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> number;

    for (number = 0; number < 5; number++)
        if (pInStore[number] > 0)
            cout << "There are " << pInStore[number] << "of that item available." << endl;
}

// Print Report Definition

void printReport (vector<string>& itemID, vector<string>& itemName, vector<int>& pOrdered,
                  vector<int>& pInStore, vector<int>& pSold, vector<double>& manufPrice,
                  vector<double>& sellingPrice)
{
    unsigned int i;
    int totalItems = 0;
    double totalInventory = 0;

    cout << "               AJ's Hardware Store     " << endl << endl;
    cout << "itemID ItemName pOrdered pInStore pSold manufPrice sellingPrice" << endl;
    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setprecision(2);

    for (i = 0; i < itemID.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << left;
        cout << setw(7) << itemID.at(i);
        cout << setw(15) << itemName.at(i);
        cout << right;
        cout << setw(8) << pOrdered.at(i);
        cout << setw(9) << pInStore.at(i);
        cout << setw(6) << pSold.at(i);
        cout << setw(11) << manufPrice.at(i);
        cout << setw(13) << sellingPrice.at(i) << endl;

        totalInventory += pInStore.at(i) * sellingPrice.at(i);
        totalItems += pInStore.at(i);
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Total Inventory: $" << totalInventory << endl;
    cout << "Total number of items in the store: " << totalItems << endl;
    

}
```

I'm getting a segmentation error which I've never encountered and this chapter (Ch16.23 Malik 8th Edition) is new to me. I believe there's something wrong with the way I'm trying to load the vectors, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks, in advance, for any guidance.

Comment: Where do you call `push_back`, `insert`, `emplace_back`, or `resize` anywhere in your code to size the vectors appropriately?  A vector doesn't grow by itself by using `[]`.  And note, having seven parallel arrays is not good.  Instead, a single `struct` or `class` that contains seven vectors would be used.

Comment: Doh, okay, so I gather I was treating it too much like an array. Well I assume, as I take the input, I can then use .push_back? Which, doesn't that itself update the size of a vector? In the getInventory function?

Comment: This is why you should start with a very small [main program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25f56d9ccbaf5db2) and practice the basic vector operations, instead of writing all of this code and realizing the basic operations on vectors are done incorrectly.

Comment: In getInventory you need something like `while(inFile >> col1 >> col2 >> ...) { v1.push_back(col1); v2.push_back(col2); ... }`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right. I literally chose the extra credit problem, rather than practicing the simple elements first. I'll do some practice and revisit this!

Comment: *Use seven parallel vectors to store the information.* What the actual <expletive deleted>. There has to be a point to this requirement, but I'm not seeing it. Are they trying to teach you to be a bad programmer?

Comment: @user4581301 Maybe this is a setup for the next question concerning sorting on one of those vectors and outputting the sorted information.  I've seen it before.

Comment: It's literally the last problem of the chapter. It leads to nothing. The next chapter is linked lists which we will not cover, because finals are next week. All resources tell me it's a bad way to do things, but that's why I guess it was extra cred.  Thanks again all, for taking a look. I have an idea now, where to start(over) at least.

Comment: Pity you miss out on the linked list. It's another tool you don't use all that much in "real life" programming because unless it's used just right, it's cripplingly slow and space inefficient. But I don't think there's a homework assignment in wide use that packs in more education/testing-of-knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault error is because you are accessing the memory you are not allowed to (or did not considered for you yet). Consider using "push_back" (or some other functions that Im not aware of) to insert an item to vector. This is how you add a new item to a vector.

And this part of your code does not make any sense :

```
...

cin >> number;

    for (number = 0; number < 5; number++)
        if (pInStore[number] > 0)
            cout << "There are " << pInStore[number] << "of that item available." << endl;

...
```

Also I recommend to make a structure type like below and then creat a vector of it. Because you need to know with item of vector is related to which item in another one :

```
struct itemName {
   int itemName;
   int itemID; // or something that is unique for each item( product )
}
```

This way you can make a relation between different properties of an item ( a product ).

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my code, removed some stuff, got a (somewhat) working function, using temporary variables, but still running into that segment and some weird stuff when doing the item search.

Comment: @iamjarvi Did you try debugging your code?